# Loop though database with foreach

Tags: php, postgresql, foreach

I want to browse data from my postgre database with a "foreach". So I made my request like that :

```
    $conn_string = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test_postgre user=postgres password='1234'";
    $dbconn = pg_connect($conn_string);

    $sql = "SELECT id_traitement FROM public.traitement WHERE id_essai='.$id_essai.';";
    $res = pg_query($sql) or die("Pb avec la requete: $sql");

    $data = pg_fetch_all($res);
```

And I get my values with "`pg_fetch_all`".

After that, I'm looking for compare the data in my database (get with the request) and the data in my web page. So I created this loop :

```
foreach($array as $ligne_web)
    {
        foreach($data['id_traitement'] as $ligne_base)
        {
            if(($ligne_web[0] == $ligne_base) and ($flag))
            {

                //update de la ligne
                update_traitement($id_traitement,$traitement,$code_traitement,$id_essai);
                $flag2 = false;
                break 1;


            }

        }
        if(($flag) and ($flag2))
        {
            insert_traitement($id_traitement,$traitement,$code_traitement,$id_essai);
        }
    }
```

When I try to run it, firebug tells me : Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()`. So I don't know how to browse the rows in the database. Certainly my problem is in my `foreach`, but I don't find what's wrong. 
Help please !

Comment: I think its `if(($ligne_web[0] == $ligne_base) && ($flag))` inside for loops

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com Thank you, I updated but I still have the error

Comment: whats the `$array` ? I believe firebug may tell you which line is error, can you point out the firebug did execute to the inner `foreach` or it stoppd at outer one.

Comment: @fuyushimoya The $array is my data from my web page. And firebug found the error on the second foreach, so I think that the problem is how I call the array from the request (with $data)

Comment: can you assign $data['id_traitement'] to a variable , and insert it into second foreach and try running

Comment: @AnirbanN Thanks but always the same error

Comment: can you post some sample data to http://sqlfiddle.com/, so it would be helpful in debugging

Comment: @AnirbanN It's the first time I use sqlfiddle so I don't know if it's what you expect.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddb25/2

Comment: @Lison what(how or where) $array value comes from ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your second `foreach` needs to be '`$data`' instead of `$data['id_traitement']`

So your code need to changed to ,

```
foreach($arr as $ligne_web)

    {
        foreach($data as $ligne_base) // <-- Here is the correction 

        {
            if(($ligne_web[0] == $ligne_base) and ($flag))

            {

                 ------ REST of your Codes ------
```

Comment: Sorry, it doens't work yet. And for your previous question, my $array comes from a handsontable in my web page. I send it with ajax and get it in json, but I already used it as an array and it worked, so it's realy a problem with the array from the database.  @Anirban N

Comment: I wonder if "pg_fetch_all" is the right expression to use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found an answer. Instead of an array $data from my database, and directly after the request, I created a new array.
Here is my code :

```
    $conn_string = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test_postgre user=postgres password='1234'";
    $dbconn = pg_connect($conn_string);

    $sql = "SELECT id_traitement FROM public.traitement WHERE id_essai='.$id_essai.';";
    $res = pg_query($sql) or die("Pb avec la requete: $sql");

    $tableau_database_final = array();
    while ($data = pg_fetch_all($res)) //Here is my array 
    {
        $tableau_database = array('id_traitement'=>$data['id_traitement']);
        array_push($tableau_database_final,$tableau_database);
    }

    $flag2 = true;

    foreach($array as $ligne_web)
    {
        foreach($tableau_database_final as $ligne_base)
        {
            echo ($ligne_web[0]);
            echo ($ligne_base);


            if(($ligne_web[0] == $ligne_base)) //Si il existe une ligne ayant déjà le même id traitement
            {

                //update de la ligne
                update_traitement($id_traitement,$traitement,$code_traitement,$id_essai);
                $flag2 = false;
                break 1;


            }

        }
        if(($flag) && ($flag2))
        {
            //insert_traitement($id_traitement,$traitement,$code_traitement,$id_essai);
        }
    }
```